# Storage permission not working for Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I want to give storage permission for my app. My code working perfect till Marshmallow, only problem in Nougat

The below method always return false in nougat even permission granted manually from settings.

```
private boolean checkWriteExternalPermission() {

    String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    int res = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(
            permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

I used this for Nougat and allow permission but above method still returns false.

```
void storagePermission(){
    StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
    StorageVolume volume = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
    Intent intent = volume.createAccessIntent(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why are you using `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()`? When you switch to [using `checkSelfPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)), what happens?

Comment: Any other way to check permission granted or not for 7+? or i need to populate permission dialog always for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use libs:  ***https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher***

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.storagePermissionWithCheck(this);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
// NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
}


@NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
void storagePermission(){
StorageManager sm =(StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
StorageVolume volume = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
Intent intent = volume.createAccessIntent(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}

 @OnPermissionDenied(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
void showDeniedForCamera() {
  // don't allow code here
}

@OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
void showNeverAskForCamera() {
    // neverAskAgain code here
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how this will address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code:

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){
        if(requestCode==1) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(),
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```